# Is there a way to gracefully close the running application via the Visual Studio menus/toolbars?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Is there a way to gracefully close the running application (e.g. inject the WM_CLOSE message) using Visual Studio's (I'm using 2013) menu/toolbar commands?

Obviously, this will not work if you are paused on a breakpoint, unless you first continue.

I ask because my application is often not in view (covered by another app) while I'm debugging and perhaps not after I continue. Using "Stop Debugging" stops the application immediately as far as I understand. As such, the HttpListener I'm using for example does not stop and close nicely. Then connecting again in another session requires jumping through hoops with the browser.

I've considered using something like AutoHotkey. Are there solutions outside of menu Tools-External Tools?

Even if External Tools is the only way to do it, I haven't found a way to get the currently running executable as an argument. I can get close with $(BinDir), but it is based on the active file.

Comment: Why not use Task manager? A simple and easy way.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed yes, it does, my apologies as I was having a geriatric moment

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed Task manager works (but so does using the windows Taskbar). I was looking for something a bit more seemless within Visual Studio. I cobbled together a solution, but it's clunky. Will post soon.

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought that by _"my application is often not in view"_, you meant that no window is shown or accessible via the taskbar.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed added clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a clunky solution using Visual Studio's External Tools to a bat file that calls an AutoHotkey (AHK) script. It would work better if you could reliably get the path to the executing binary:

Limitations:

- Depends on having a source file active that is included in the binary you're trying to close (i.e. if you have a source file selected that is part of another binary.
- Probably depends on your target being a Windows executable.

**Visual Studio menu Tools-External Tools...:**
Title: `Close Program`
Command: `<path to bat file>`
Arguments: `$(BinDir)$(TargetName).vshost$(TargetExt)`

**Bat file**

```
@echo off
"<Path to AHK script>" %1
```

**Autohotkey**

```
Path := A_Args[1]
WinClose, ahk_exe %Path%
```